# Re index and sort a multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to Re index and Sort a multidimensional PHP array, keeping in mind that if some of the inside arrays do not have a particular index and others do, we want to just jump over to the next index in that particular inside array

E.g the source array below does not have array index 4 in subject_1 and subject_3 but has it in subject_2

```
            Array
            (
            [subject_1] => Array
            (
            [2] => a
            [6] => b
            )

            [subject_2] => Array
            (
            [2] => c
            [4] => d
            [6] => e
            )

            [subject_3] => Array
            (
            [2] => f
            [6] => g
            )
            )
```

So, the expected result array should be something like the below

```
            Array
            (
            [subject_1] => Array
            (
            [0] => a
            [2] => b
            )       
            [subject_2] => Array
            (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
            [2] => e
            )

            [subject_3] => Array
            (
            [0] => f
            [2] => g
            )
            )
            )
            )
```

The issue with the below code is that it does know if the index exists on all sub arrays before sorting

```
            $all_incoming_keys = array();
            foreach($p2 as $key => $value){
            $all_incoming_keys[] = $key;
            }
            for($sp2 = 0; $sp2 < count($p2); $sp2++){
            sort($p2[$all_incoming_keys[$sp2]]);
            array_values($p2[$all_incoming_keys[$sp2]]);
            }
```

It this code the right approach for the situation or is there a function that I am missing

Comment: If you just want to re-index stuff, then use `array_values`.

Comment: I don't see any point at all in doing this. The same code you use to reindex the array now could be used to iterate over the existing array later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to reindex the keys based on the position is a list of unique keys, you first need to decide this order.  This code goes through all *subjects* and merges all of the keys into 1 array (`$all_incoming_keys`).  This is then processed to create a unique list of keys (in numerical order) and creates a list with an associated position.

```
$all_incoming_keys = [];
// Extract all of the keys
foreach ( $a as $subjects ) {
    $all_incoming_keys = array_merge ($all_incoming_keys, array_keys($subjects));
}
sort($all_incoming_keys);
// Create sequential list of different values
$all_incoming_keys = array_flip(array_values(array_unique($all_incoming_keys)));
print_r($all_incoming_keys);
```

This gives...

```
Array
(
    [2] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [6] => 2
)
```

The second part then just passes through the subjects again and copies the value for each item into a new array with the key from the above list...

```
$newA = [];
foreach ( $a as $subjectName => $subjects ) {
    foreach ( $subjects as $key => $subject ){
        $newA[$subjectName][$all_incoming_keys[$key]] = $subject;
    }
}

print_r($newA);
```

Which in your example, should give...

```
Array
(
    [subject_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [2] => b
        )

    [subject_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
            [2] => e
        )

    [subject_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => f
            [2] => g
        )

)
```